# Jquery UI Fade not working in IE

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-tabs

I'm working with a simple Jquery UI script that changes tabs on mouseover and auto rotates.  The script functions perfectly in all browsers except IE.  In IE the rotate and Mouseover works, but the fade doesn't work.  You can view the script at http://www.1tryten.com.  It's the main banner that I'm using here.  The script I'm using is:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
 $("#tabs").tabs({
 event: 'mouseover',
 fx: {
    opacity: 'toggle'
     }
 }).tabs('rotate', 5000, true); 
});
```

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this [article on opacity in different browsers](http://css-tricks.com/64-css-transparency-settings-for-all-broswers/). IE uses different CSS syntax to set opacity Maybe this could be the cause? Does `$("#tabs").fadeIn().fadeOut();` work as expected?

Comment: You mean fadeIn / fadeOut doesn't work? What version of jQuery are you running? Try updating?